# How to map colors to certain values in a heatmap with plt.hist2d function?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I am plotting a Faceted Grid of heatmaps using `matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d` as an argument to the map function of the `seaborn.FacetGrid` object, the problem is the color representation of values is not consistent across the different plots.
How to map the color palette values to constant values for all the plots?

```
def hist2dgrid(x, y, **kwargs):
    palette = kwargs.pop('color')
    bins_x = np.arange(0,24+1.5,1.5)
    bins_y = np.arange(0,36+3,2)
    plt.hist2d(x, y, bins = [bins_x, bins_y], cmap = palette, cmin = 0.5)
    plt.colorbar(label='count')

g= sns.FacetGrid(data=df_clean,col='start_time_day_name',col_wrap = 3)
g.map(hist2dgrid, 'start_time_hour_decimal', 'avg_trip_speed_kmh',color='viridis_r');
```

Output is:
[image: FacetGrid of heatmaps]

Comment: Maybe useful: http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/three_variable_histogram.html

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks for your effort, I know how to use the website though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass to [**`matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) `vmin` and `vmax` parameters:

Result on a random dataset, without above parameters:

[image]

Result on the same dataset, with above parameters:

```
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins = [bins_x, bins_y], cmap = palette, cmin = 0.5, vmin = 30, vmax = 40)
```

[image]